# Mips Assembly Language printing out digits in separate lines

Tags: string, loops

I have question regarding how to ready every each two digits separated by Space. You will have only seven two digits.

For example you have a user to input: 54 32 65 98 67 12 45

I want to print out every two digits in separate line.
54\n
32\n
65\n
98\n
67\n
12\n
45\n

And thank you :D

Comment: Iterate over the string contents and print a CRLF sequence (13, 10) whenever you encounter a space character.

Comment: Any language can manipulate strings, bytes, digits.  This question has nothing specific to MIPS, don't  see why it is tagged.